# Spring RestTemplate - ErrorHandling

Tags: java, spring-boot, error-handling, httpresponse, resttemplate

I am calling Restservice through RestTemplate through below code :

ResponseEntity response = new RestTemplate().postForEntity(url, request, String.class);

whenever something wrong comes from Client , it throws below error :

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:708)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:415)
```

But when I hit directly the same input request through SOAPUI or Postman ,I get this error like below :

```
    <Errors>
   <Error ErrorCode="YFS10003" ErrorDescription="YFS:Invalid Order" ErrorUniqueExceptionId="10.148.201.9815264936514610000000000060" HttpCode="400">
      <Attribute Name="ErrorDescription" Value="YFS:Invalid Order"/>
      <Attribute Name="ErrorUniqueExceptionId" Value="10.148.201.9815264936514610000000000060"/>
      <Attribute Name="ErrorCode" Value="YFS10003"/>
      <Attribute Name="HttpCode" Value="400"/>
   </Error>
</Errors>
```

What I need is , how can I store or catch above exception/error what is coming through client in code and print to have more detailed knowledge about why error came rather than getting a generic error as 400 Bad request.

Is there is way through ResponseErrorHandler class ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's likely that same end point can return json and xml. When you don't put `application/json` on the header it might return xml.Try putting header in SOAPUI or POSTMan

Answer (score 0):

If you take a closer look to the RestTemplate API, you can find the [RestTemplate#setErrorHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#setErrorHandler-org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler-) method where you can define a custom ErrorHandler and execute the code you want, in your case, print out the message itself.

By default, the RestTemplate is using the [DefaultResponseErrorHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/DefaultResponseErrorHandler.html) which will simply just throw the exception in case any error happened.